# Is pygame volume linear or exponential?

Tags: python, pygame

I read that a common mistake in game development regards the volume option. It showed how a derease from 100% to 50% volume is decreasing by half, but then 10% to 0% is a decrease by 100%. In essence, the volume decreases more quickly at lower volumes, and faster at higher volumes. I'm not aware of the math, but the solution was to raise the volume decimal to the power of euler's number. In pygame, you input a value from 0-1 as the volume for pygame.mixer.set_volume(), I am wondering if it would be best to ignore the exponentiation, or to calculate it?

Comment: I would ignore it. perceptual loudness is a very deep subject (like perceptual color). The linearity of the volume bar on my TV is not something I worry about... Trust that the libsdl authors did a good enough job figuring out how to set volume between 0-100% and move on.

Comment: In my testing, using the set_volume() function meant that the user could only access values in about half of the range, depending on their device volume. (At 100% device volume I could barely hear 0.1 pygame volume, but at 20% device vol, 100% was perfect volume.) Ideally if there is a simple solution or equation I can implement to convert the original 0-1 value to a new 0-1 value which would create a smoother transition going up, that would be fantastic.

Comment: It's possible they aren't using DB in the volume calculation, and just multiplying by an amplitude ratio. In that case you could do a log scale conversion to DB. I would make sure to try it on a variety of computer setups though. Sound drivers and hardware could be at play here.

Comment: Perceptual sound is proportional to [DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel), which is IIRC: `amplitude = 10^(DB/20)`

Comment: Definitely test several computers though with several hardware/software combinations and several audio sources (test files) of various format.

Comment: I don't fully understand your proposal to use a log scale conversion. Perhaps I didn't previously mention, but I would like to convert a value (from 0 to 1, which the user uses to control the volume) into another value, which can be input to set_volume() to set the volume, also from 0 to 1. It seems like I would need to map it out somehow, like {1 : 1, 0.5 : 0.7, 0.1 : 0.2, 0.05}, but this is not a good solution at all, hence a formula. How would I go about doing this? I don't think we can access the decibel volume in pygame. Thanks

Comment: I believe I've found the solution to be raising to a specific power. I'm using 2.72 but will possibly adjust later. Thanks for your help, will definitely test on different machines as well.

Comment: Do not add the answer to the question. If you have found the solution, write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame volume is very linear so it creates a strange effect when changing volume at various ranges. Raise the volume in the range of 0-1 to the power of your choosing, e seems to work well.